# Regexp find and replace all links without image tag

Tags: regex, hyperlink, search-regex

I have Wordpress site. My task find all internal links without href ancors, and text of link exclude img tag. 
Now I have:

```
/<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*["'](?!(?:#|javascript\s*:))([^"']+)[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/si
```

Now retrun:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="http://happymodern.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/бар_19.jpg"><img class="alignnone wp-image-34 size-full" src="http://happymodern.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/бар_19.jpg" alt="бар_19" width="784" height="560" /></a></p> <p style="text-align: justify;">
```

My task find all link with text (without ancor and image tag) for examp `<a href="/category/testpsot">text contain</a>`
and delete link and leave the text

```
text contain
```

PS: I am use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: Please provide the language you are using the regex in. As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool. This is especially important when dealing with HTML parsing.

Comment: I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: Regex bad idea for idea. Use a dom parser to construct a tree for the document. Php has good libraries for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/326370

Comment: @IlyaKogan: Well, all those do-not-parse-HTML-with-regex links are useless if OP is determined to only use the search regex plugin. It only supports regex. Max, can you use PHP code to process the string in question? Then, you'd be able to use DOMDocument with DOMXPath.

Comment: Just in case, you may try `<a\b[^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*["'](?!(?:#|javascript\s*:))([^"']+)[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR7kU5/2)), but note it is still unclear what you need, and this regex might cause other issues now or in future.